# FastReport Net - How to register a data source?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, fastreport

Fragment from the code:

```
WebReport webReport = new WebReport(); // создаем объект 

    webReport.Report.Load(this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/frx/krsPrInfo.frx"));
    webReport.Width = Unit.Percentage(100); ;  // задаем ширину
    webReport.Height = Unit.Percentage(100); ; // задаем высоту 
    webReport.ReportDataSources = "appData";
    webReport.RegisterData(wmasters, "appData");           
    ViewBag.WebReport = webReport; // передаем данные во View
```

I get an error all the time that this does not exist in the current context.

> ERROR: (Cell1): Error CS0103: The name "appData" is missing in the current context

The code took from there [FastReport .Net 2013.2 MVC](https://www.fast-report.com/en/blog/37/show/)

Comment: in example you have `"AppData"` not `"appData"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in your designed report is there a table named "appData"?.Secondly You should set your source table (appData)  to fastreport data band object 'Data1' or something like that. Check your Report in design mode for the name of Data Band object.

```
   webReport.Report.Load(this.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/frx/krsPrInfo.frx"));
        webReport.Width = Unit.Percentage(100); ;  // задаем ширину
        webReport.Height = Unit.Percentage(100); ; // задаем высоту 
       // webReport.ReportDataSources = "appData";//You dont need this
        webReport.RegisterData(wmasters, "appData");  
((FastReport.DataBand)webReport.Report.FindObject("Data1")).DataSource = webReport.Report.GetDataSource("appData");   


    ViewBag.WebReport = webReport; // передаем данные во View
```